# Dask: applying custom function to DataFrame gets error

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'd like to speed up my DataFrame manipulations and have decided to use for this aim the dask library - but cannot use it with success. I have made a test example to show my problems:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.multiprocessing import get

def testfunc(good):
  return good*good

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3], 'b' : [4,5,6], 'c' : [7,8,9]})
ddata = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

df1 = ddata.map_partitions(lambda df: df.apply((lambda row: testfunc(*row)), axis=1)).compute(get=get)
```

But running this code I receive an error: TypeError: testfunc() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given. Could you explain what is wrong in my code...

Answer (score 1):

This will work with a minor change. You're currently unpacking the `row` object by using the asterisk. You probably want to directly pass the row, as is.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
​
def testfunc(good):
    return good*good
​
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3], 'b' : [4,5,6], 'c' : [7,8,9]})
ddata = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
​
df1 = ddata.map_partitions(lambda df: df.apply((lambda row: testfunc(row)), axis=1)).compute()
print(df1)
   a   b   c
0  1  16  49
1  4  25  64
2  9  36  81
```

For more information, you might want to check out the [expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists) Python docs